# Looking for vulnerabilities in my code (split method)

Tags: python, security

Here I've tried to recreate the `str.split()` method in Python. I've tried and tested this code and it works fine, but I'm looking for vulnerabilities to correct. Do check it out and give feedback, if any.
Edit:Apologies for not being clear,I meant to ask you guys for exceptions where the code won't work.I'm also trying to think of a more refined way without looking at the source code.

```
def splitt(string,split_by = ' '):
    output = []
    x = 0
    for i in range(string.count(split_by)):
        output.append((string[x:string.index(split_by,x+1)]).strip())
        x = string.index(split_by,x+1)
    output.append((((string[::-1])[:len(string)-x])[::-1]).strip())

    return output
```

Comment: What do you mean by "vulnerabilities"? Corner cases where the function breaks?

Comment: I would also like to know what you mean.

Comment: The term "vulnerability" is usually used to refer to security problems, not programming errors in general (although many bugs can lead to vulnerabilities depending on where the erroneous code is used).

Comment: ya sorry guys for being blunt,I meant exceptions where the code won't work as expected, or more efficient ways to do recreate the split method

Answer (score 1):

There are in fact a few problems with your code:

- by searching from `x+1`, you may miss an occurance of `split_by` at the very start of the string, resulting in `index` to fail in the last iteration
- you are calling `index` more often than necessary
- `strip` only makes sense if the separator is whitespace, and even then might remove more than intended, e.g. trailing spaces when splitting lines
- instead, add `len(split_by)` to the offset for the next call to `index`
- no need to reverse the string twice in the last step

This should fix those problems:

```
def splitt(string,split_by=' '):
    output = []
    x = 0
    for i in range(string.count(split_by)):
        x2 = string.index(split_by, x)
        output.append((string[x:x2]))
        x = x2 + len(split_by)
    output.append(string[x:])
    return output
```